# Problems with getting Facebook user first name with Passport.JS in Node.JS application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

I am developing a Node.js application using Express 4, MongoLab (cloud-based MongoDB), Mongoose for connecting to MongoDB, and PassportJS for Facebook authentication. I am able to successfully get a user's Profile ID, full name, and profile photo (they both show in my Mongolab account collection and render successfully in my application's HTML), however I have been unsuccessful in getting ONLY the user's first name. According to the PassportJS Facebook Strategy documentation and on other blogs on the web, a user's first name is under "givenName" and it is under an object called "name" http://passportjs.org/docs/profile. "name" does not even make it to my database. Below is my passportAuth.js file. My goal is to be able to greet the user by only their first name within my HTML. If any of you can figure out where I have gone wrong I would be extremely grateful!

```
    module.exports = function(passport, FacebookStrategy, config, mongoose){

    var chatUser = new mongoose.Schema({
    profileID:String,
    fullname:String,
    profilePic:String,
    name:Object
    })

    var userModel = mongoose.model('chatUser', chatUser);

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
    done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
    userModel.findById(id, function(err, user){
        done(err, user);
    })
    })

    passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: config.fb.appID,
    clientSecret: config.fb.appSecret,
    callbackURL: config.fb.callbackURL,
    profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'photos', 'name']
    }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done){
    //Check if the user exists in our database, if not then create one and        
    return the profile. If it does exist then return it.
    userModel.findOne({'profileID':profile.id}, function(err, result){
        if(result){
            done(null, result);
        }else{
            // Create a new user in the Mongolab account
            var newChatUser = new userModel({
                profileID:profile.id,
                fullname:profile.displayName,
                profilePic:profile.photos[0].value || '',
                name:profile.name.givenName
            });

            newChatUser.save(function(err){
                done(null, newChatUser);
            })
        }
        })
    })
    )    
    }
```

Example MongoDB collection I am seeing. Missing the name/givenName string. Should be something like "name: John" or "givenName = John"

```
    {
    "_id": {
    "$oid": "1234abcd"
    },
    "profileID": "5678qwe",
    "fullname": "John Doe",
    "profilePic": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-xpa1=1234",
    "__v": 0
    }
```

Comment: Can you include an example document that you're actually getting from mongo?

Comment: @AshleyB  please see my updated question. Hope this helps. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why givenName isn't there, have you tried multiple accounts / logging at as soon as if first comes in to your app? One way to potentally hack together a first name would be to do `fullname.split(" ")[0];` (get the first word in `fullname`).

Comment: @AshleyB unfortunately, the split would not work, since the fullname is rendered in my HTML from the database using mustaches {{user.fullname}}. Do you know how to apply a JS split or regex to that? Very much appreciated!

Comment: I think a better way to do it would be to add a [mongoose middle-ware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) that sets the `firstName`if the given name is updated like so (not tested this, but it should work): `schema.pre('save', function(next) {

  if (!this.isModified('givenName')) {
    return next();
  }

  this.firstname = this.givenName.split(" ")[0];
  next();
});`

 What happens if you log the result of `profile.name` inside your else block? Do you seen the givenName field then?

Comment: @AshleyB I tried the mongoose middle-ware code you provided, but it did not work.

Comment: module.exports = function(passport, FacebookStrategy, config, mongoose){
    
    var chatUser = new mongoose.Schema({
        profileID:String,
        fullname:String,
        profilePic:String,
        firstname:String,
        
    })
        chatUser.pre('save', function(next) { if (!this.isModified('fullname')) { return next(); } this.firstname = this.fullname.split(" ")[0]; next(); })
        
    var userModel = mongoose.model('chatUser', chatUser);

Comment: Your code above is missing a final `}` but I think the problem is that it tries to do it before it gets saved, the first time the document i created `this.fullname` won't exist yet. Not sure of a way around it.